# What steps i need to configure ssl on haproxy/iis

Tags: iis, ssl, load-balancing, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I have two web server and one haproxy load balancer in front of them.

I want to setup ssl connection for my login page. Can someone give me life cycle steps what i need to do? Can i make this with single ssl certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Purchase an SSL certificate
2. Decide where you will terminate the SSL. Pound and stunnel are commonly used, although dev versions of HAProxy now include SSL support.
3. Install pound/stunnel/whatever on your load balancer + configure it with cert from (1). Pound/stunnel/whatever will listen on 443 and you can just pass back to your HAProxy instance.
4. Re-direct all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS or make your application aware of the SSL.  E.g., redirect http://foo.com/login to https://foo.com/login (this should be secure).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, this is what a saw on other place :). Ill try this config next days

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your current haproxy configuration. If you're using something that depends on being able to inspect the payload of the session, then you will either need to offload your SSL process before haproxy, or upgrade to haproxy 1.5 to use it's SSL offloading capabilities.

If you're not using anything that needs to inspect the payload, then you just need to make sure you're listening on port 443. Configure IIS with your SSL certificates.